# Rails destroy_all undo

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, irb, undo, destroy

I've accidentally erased all the records from one my model.

```
Model.destroy_all
```

For the output I've received a large list for all the records that have been destroyed.

```
=> [#<Model id: 1, some_attribute: "Hello World">, #<Model id: 2, some_attribute: " Hello World 2">, etc etc etc]
```

But, I've got it a text. 
Can I do anything, using IRB, to return the records back ?

This is very, VERY urgent! Any help is appreciated.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script should do the trick:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

str = "#<Model id: 1, some_attribute: #<BigDecimal:4ba0730,'0.0',9(18)>, another_attribute: \"Hello World\">, #<Model id: 2, some_attribute: \" Hello World 2\">"

str.scan(/#?<(\w+) (.+?)>(?=, #|$)/) do |m|
    model = Object.const_get(m[0])
    m[1].gsub!(/#<BigDecimal:.+?('.+?').+?>/, "BigDecimal.new(\\1)")
    eval("model.create(#{m[1]})")
end
```

This also handles instances of BigDecimal. In case you need to handle other special types you can just add another call to `gsub!`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

How can I enhance my second capture group if I have a "#<BigDecimal:4ba0730,'0.0',9(18)" for one of model's attributes ?
Any code example ?
This is the reason why your approach is not working for me right now

Comment: Careful with double quotes, I had a problem when including dates in mine, datetime's had double quotes in them, but by doing `str = 'blah'` it seemed to work

Answer (score 2):

here's a quick test I made on my model:

1.
    `pry(main)> output = JobUser.first(10).to_s`

```
=> "[#<JobUser id: 10001, instagram_user_id: 297705889, job_id: 2, invited: true, created_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\", updated_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\">, #<JobUser id: 10002, instagram_user_id: 36823356, job_id: 2, invited: true, created_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\", updated_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\">, #<JobUser id: 10003, instagram_user_id: 509682835, job_id: 2, invited: true, created_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\", updated_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\"> ....
```

2.

`parsed = output.gsub('#<', '').gsub('>', '').gsub(/^\[/, '').gsub(/\]$/, '').split('JobUser').map(&:strip)`

=>

```
     "id: 10001, instagram_user_id: 297705889, job_id: 2, invited: true, created_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\", updated_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\",",
     "id: 10002, instagram_user_id: 36823356, job_id: 2, invited: true, created_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\", updated_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\",",
     "id: 10003, instagram_user_id: 509682835, job_id: 2, invited: true, created_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\", updated_at: \"2013-09-23 21:53:37\"...
```

3.
`parsed.shift` because the first element in array will be a blank string

4.
`records = parsed.map { |serialized_record| JobUser.new(eval "{ #{serialized_record} }") }`

then you should probably run something like `records.each { |record| record.save }`

Please note that you should replace `JobUser` with your model name. 
The point is you'll have to parse the string and insert it back into database

good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I'm going to try it right away

Comment: Can you suggest what should I do if I have a BigDecimal column entry ?
 
Because of it I have an error at step 4: "syntax error, unexpected tLABEL" 

Do I need to parse it somehow ? Thank you